# Is there a way to have type specification when passing a variable to a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, specifications

In a language like C# I must specify the type of the objects that are passed into a given function. If I have a class like so:

`class Thing
{
    public static someFunc(int input)
    {
        return input * 2
    }
}`

Then if I am in main I can call that function through another function by specifying the type of the variable that will be passed as an argument:

```
public static otherFunc(Thing item, int num)
{
    return item.someFunc(num)
}
```

though the example is not optimal, I make it just to show that I can access functions from the Thing class within a separate function by specifying that a Thing object will be passed to that function.

Python does not have this level of type specification, thus I can see no way of achieving the same result. If I have a function which I defined in a class from a separate file, but I want to run it through a function where an object of that class type will be used to run that function, how can I access that class function in a separate function?

Comment: You just access it. `item.someFunc(num)`.

Comment: What you have written in `C#` can be written in exactly the same way in `Python`, just without the static type checking.

Comment: I'm with @pvg on this one. Your question really seems to be "How can I translate this code from C# to Python". In any case, your going to have to be more specific if you want a useful answer. What attempts have you made at solving this problem, and where exactly are you stuck.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass it or how to pass it and have the compiler verify that what you are passing is infact a `Thing` object? For the later you have [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code in Python (lets use separate file also) like this:

First.py

```
class Thing:
    @staticmethod
    def someFunc(input):
        return input * 2
```

Second.py

```
def otherFunc(item, num):
    return item.someFunc(num)
```

Now the call site:

Main.py

```
from First import Thing
from Second import otherFunc

t = Thing()
otherFunc(t,2)
```

So I can't see what it is you think that Python cannot do.